# Does TensorFlow Autograph recognising the "is" operator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider the following Python code

```
@tf.function(autograph=True)
def foo(x, flag):
   if flag is True:
       x = tf.add(x, 1)
   return x
```

Now consider, this code where the only difference is the "is" is changed to a "=="

```
@tf.function(autograph=True)
def foo(x, flag):
   if flag == True:
       x = tf.add(x, 1)
   return x
```

In the case where `flag` is a Tensor, the first code does not evaluate correctly. I think AutoGraph does not recognise the "is" operator. Can anyone help me understand why this is the case and how I can fix it in the remainder of my code without manually finding and replacing "is" operators. If anyone can confirm that this is an issue and not me being silly, I'll open up an issue on GitHub.

Comment: This looks like expected behaviour to me, no? in the first case the `flag` is a Tensor object, so it's not the `True` object, even if it contains the `True` object. In the second case the `==` succeeds because the `Tensor`s `__eq__` is written in such a way that it evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes I see what you're saying. I'm not sure if this design pattern is PEP 285 compliant though. True and False should be considered singletons and it would be good if Autograph could recognise the use of such Tensors are singletons rather than Tensors.

Comment: The reason I say this is because whilst you may have True, False values are python objects, Autograph might convert them into Tensors and hence are no longer python singletons.

Comment: Thank you for your help though Frederik :)

Comment: Using `is` where you really mean `==` is bad practice regardless of the types involved. `flag` by itself in a boolean context is almost always preferable to `flag == True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries like Tensorflow, sympy, SQLAlchemy and others take advatage of Python's "operator overloading" feature - that is, for the specialized objects defined in those libraries, the comparison operators like "==, >, <, !=" - actually, all other mathematical operators as well - "+, -, *, /", and others that are words, not symbols, such as "in, not"  - are specialized so that code defined in the library is called when an operator is encountered.

This allows the libraries to augment the operator behavior.  The thing is that some of these "operators", that syntactically behave just like the others, do not  trigger, and cannot trigger any custom code - their behavior is the same across all objects, and, when one does think about it, they would not make sense otherwise. Three such operators are "and, or, **is**".

In the case of `is`, Python use it solely for identity comparison - if the object on the left is the same (and that implies being at the same memory location) than the object on the right.

So, if "`flag` is a Tensor" as you put it, it will never be the `True` object (which is a singleton).  And there is nothing tensorflow can add in the code for the Tensor class to change this behavior.

On the other hand, the  `==` operator will cause Python to call the `__eq__` method on the object class, which can perform all sort of operations.

Comment: But shouldn't AutoGraph be able to convert the Python code and recognise the use of "is" in the context of a comparison with a singleton? 

But thanks - this explanation made sense.

Comment: I don't know Autograph, but it is rather little likely it resorts to extract the source code, and recompile it by using its own semantics, when everything else can be achieved with operator overloading.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot! Ever since the release of TF2.0, Autograph has been causing me all sorts of problems with debugging and using the default Eager Execution is just really slow and memory inefficient. TF1.15 sessions were much better even though it meant lagging behind PyTorch for academic research.